# How can i get the reason for the batch file executing failure using c#?

Tags: c#

I am using the code below to notify if there are any problem executing the batchfile which starts a process. This message box shows me the content of batchfile and does not shows the problem caused. How can i get the reason for the batch file executing failure ?

```
   System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filename);
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                System.Diagnostics.Process listFiles;
                listFiles = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
                System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = listFiles.StandardOutput;
                listFiles.WaitForExit(2000);
                if (listFiles.HasExited)
                {
                    string output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(output);
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading the content of `listFiles.StandardError` rather than `StandardOutput`.